# XLPagerTabStrip switching horizontal scrolling tabs to multi-row tabs

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2, xlpagertabstrip

I have a view controller which extends **ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController** and there are *9 tabs* to be displayed in the **ButtonBarView**. I'm wondering if it's possible to *disable* the horizontal scrolling and make it into *3 tabs per row* with 3 rows in total being shown.

I've looked into its documentation and source codes on GitHub and tag on StackOverflow but couldn't find any solutions to it.

[XLPagerTabStrip GitHub](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Issue:**
[image: Scrollable Tabs]

**Trying to achieve:**
[image: Multi-row tabs]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can create the menu with tabs by own using collectionView and hide the default menu of 'xlpagertabstrip' library. You just use the only paging feature of this library and create the top menu using collectionView.

I did this by this way as I explained and using this library:
https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu (Awesome library)

Comment: Thanks for your input! :) I've tried your way but unfortunately it was quite a bit of work. I managed to make it multi-row by overriding its UICollectionView's default scroll direction and set to vertical. From there, I adjusted the cell's height and width via sizeForItemAtIndexPath method. That's all is needed to achieve it :)

Comment: Good to hear that you achieve it !!